# Do I have to remove eventHandlers in a finalizer?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a model class that has a `Saved` event. The idea is that if two viewmodels use that model object, if one of them changes it, the other will be updated.

Do I have to remove the event handler when I am no longer using its view model? Here is my code:

```
protected AbstractEntityViewModel(AbstractEntity ae)
{
    this.ae = ae;

    ae.Saved += delegate(object o, EventArgs e) 
    { 
        base.OnPropertyChanged(null);
    };
}
```

Is this ok, or do I need to change this so that I can `-=` get rid of the delegate when the viewmodel is no longer used?

Comment: it would never get to executing the finalizer if there are still references to the object - you will have to do this somewhere else e.g. the `Dispose` method.

Comment: @BrokenGlass So how does this work - I implement `IDisposable` and remove the event handler in `OnDispose`? Do I have to do anything else after that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Long and short of it is yes. The secondary object can not be disposed of if the AbstractEntity object still has a reference to it. IF there is a chance that the object will be disposed and the Event is still around (this holds true for static events too) then you need to manually remove the eventhandler or the object will not be disposed.

Answer (score 4):

### Direction of event References

To know whether you really need to detach the event handler, you've first got to understand that:

```
ae.Saved += delegate(object o, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    base.OnPropertyChanged(null);
};
```

means `ae` is now referencing `this`. So the object with the event is referencing the object with the event handler. It's not the other way around (event handler referencing event).

### Objects not referenced by GC root can be collected

Furthermore, while ideally objects to be garbage collected are not referenced by any other objects, that is not strictly necessary:

The garbage collector can collect all objects which are not referenced by a GC root in any way (path). This means if you've got an insular graph of objects (objects referencing other objects of the graph, but there is no object outside the graph which is referencing an object inside the graph [no GC root either]), then the entire object graph will eventually be garbage collected. The more intertwined the graph is, the more expensive it is for the GC to collect it. Detaching event handlers helps in dissolving such graphs more speedily.

### Correctly cleaning up objects

.Net does not feature Destructors. Instead there is the `IDisposable` pattern and finalizers (see [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Long story short:

- Finalization methods (`~Foo () { }` for `class Foo`) are needed when an object manages unmanaged resources. They are called by the garbage collector when the GC is collecting the object. So the exact moment is not up to you.
- Disposable pattern can be used to clean-up managed as well as unmanaged resources. If the object has got unmanaged resources, it must still have a finalizer. Why? The `Dispose()` method is called by you. There is no guarantee that it's being executed. If the application fails to call the `Dispose()` method, there's still the GC which calls finalize. So basically doing unmanaged-resource cleanup in Dispose is just a performance improvement (which, under some circumstances, may be very important, unless you want to plug in a few more gigabytes of RAM into the computer...).

If you plan to use a finalizer i absolutely urge you to read the docs on it, because there's quite a few things which i didn't cover here. See [Implementing Finalize and Dispose to Clean Up Unmanaged Resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/b1yfkh5e%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

### Your example

To come back to your example, after you construct a `AbstractEntityViewModel`, it will stay alive as long as the `AbstractEntity` you've passed to the `AbstractEntityViewModel` stays alive and vice versa.
But when neither of those two are referenced by a GC root, both of them are garbage collected.

If you detach the event handler, the `AbstractEntityViewModel` (or rather it's concrete sub-class instance) can be garbage collected even if the `AbstractEntity` can't.

Also see: [Understanding Garbage Collection in .NET](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/understanding-garbage-collection-in-.net/)

---

Answer (score 1):

Events can be though of as being a primitive observer implementation: The subject retains a handler to every subscribed observer, meaning they are unable to be garbage collected. To allow the observer to be garbage collected, it must be removed as an observer from the subject.

The only time where event handlers do not need to be manually removed are when the subject and the observer are the same instance, as the garbage collector will detect the circular reference and subsequently finalize the object.